# Use of scanf() in C

Tags: c, scanf

I have the following question. 
In the below code, if the input is a single character, then it gets printed successfully in output window. But if more than one character is given as input, it prints each character(both alphanumeric characters) separately until all are done.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
    char c;
    printf("enter any character: \n");
    while(scanf("%c",&c)!=0)
    {
        printf("%c\t",c);
    }
    getche();
}
```

Question:
if a single character specifier (`%c`) is used in input function, then it must print only the first character and ignore the rest. But how its printing out all the input characters separately. Can anyone kindly clarify?
Am unable to add image of output screen.

Comment: The `while` loop does that.

Comment: because you are asking for it? `while(scanf("%c", &c) != 0)` will read all the input buffer. If you replace your `while` loop with an `if` statement, you'll get what you want. `if(scanf("%c", &c) == 1) { ... }`.

Comment: " it must print only the first character and ignore the rest. " --> No.  Up to 1 character is read.  The rest remain in `stdin`.

Comment: `while(scanf("%c",&c)!=0)` is an infinite loop.  Better to use `while(scanf("%c",&c) == 1)`

Comment: if the code is modified as while((a=scanf("%c",&num1))!=0), the value of a=1 remains 1, irrespective of number of characters given as input. But the return value of scanf is number of successfull inputs it reads?

Comment: C and input from the console is thorny for the beginner and hard to get perfect even for more experienced programmers. The underlying problem is that the standard library (of which scanf is a part) does not know anything about user interaction, funny as that may seem. Contrary to popular belief, `scanf()`  *does not* read from the keyboard. It reads from standard input. If, and if so, how user input reaches a program is operating system, terminal and shell dependent. In many cases a whole line is provided to the program's standard input in a chunk when the user presses enter.

Answer (score 2):

Once you enter multiple `char`s and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, all the `char`s are going to be stored in standard input. Running `scanf("%c",&c)` *once* will read one `char` and leave the rest of the inputs in the `stdin`. So, for the next time, when control reaches `scanf("%c",&c)` (due to the `while()` loop control), it will read the next `char` and so on, until the matching fails and `scanf()` returns a 0.

As mentioned in `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.2 , the conditions for `scanf()` failure, which returns `EOF` (*in case of input failure before any matching takes place*) or `0` (*in case the matching fails, which is not possible for `%c`, anyway*) is

> [...] If the length of the input
>   item is zero, the execution of the directive fails; this condition is a matching failure unless
>   end-of-file, an encoding error, or a read error prevented input from the stream, in which
>   case it is an input failure.

**TL;DR** Input buffer does not *auto-discard* itself after a call to `scanf()` If you want the buffer to be clean before you call another `scanf()`, you need to do that yourself.

Having said that, `void main()` is not a standard signature of `main()` in hosted environment. You need to use `int main(void)`, at least.

Comment: @chux Updated answer to mention the specific cases, thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

The buffer (stdin) is not empty. You are fetching only one character, but doing it in loop. If you want to fetch only one character drop the while.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` function scans `stdin` buffer for the first occurance of specified template. In your case it's a single character. But the buffer is not cleared upon completion, so if you will call `scanf` once more - you will get the next character from the stream. This behavior can be avoided using special terminal configuration. See `termios` for examples.

Answer (score 0):

Repeated execution of the code

```
scanf("%c", &c);
```

will read *every* character that is input - including the `newline` that you type. You can change it to ignore any preceding whitespace with

```
scanf(" %c", &c);
```

Note the difference is a `space` before the format specification. Apart from that, none of the input is ignored.